# How to find out common elements between two files?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sort, join

For an example, I have 2 files having following info:

File #1:

```
12
13
14
15
```

File #2:

```
12 1
13 2
14 2
15 6
16 7
17 8
```

Output File:

```
1
2
2
6
```

In the output file, I want only the second column values of file #2 which has matched with the first column of file #1. Is there any utility function for that in Linux? I'm new in shell scripting, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 9):

you could use the `join` command to join the files on a specific column, and `awk` to parse the output.

To join these files on column 1 pass the parameters `-j 1` to the join command:

```
usr@srv % join -j 1 test test2 
12 1

13 2

14 2

15 6
```

Afterwards use `awk` to print only the second column:

```
usr@srv % join -j 1 test test2 | awk '{print $2}'
1

2

2

6
```

Comment: No need for awk: `join -o 2.2 test test2`

Comment: Is there a way to specify standard output as stdin? I.e. the purpose is check common elements between all three files? Not just two? `join f1 f2 > fr; join fr f3`  -- something like `join f1 f2 f3`?

Answer (score -1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 1' file1.txt file2.txt | awk ' { print $2 } '
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding an explanation of what your code does.